# Vectorial calculus

Tags: vectors

I'm doing a calculus in which I have a vector
$$\displaystyle V=\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle a\left(x+y\right)\\
\displaystyle -ay\\
\displaystyle w_0
\end{pmatrix}$$

The thing is I need to compute the jacobian of $V$ which I found was
$$
J=\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle a &a&0\\
\displaystyle 0 & -a & 0\\
\displaystyle 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and also 
$$\displaystyle \vec{\text{grad}}\left(\vec{V}^2\right)=\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle 2a^2x+2a^2y\\
\displaystyle 2a^2y\\
\displaystyle 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\displaystyle \vec{\text{rot}}\left(\vec{V}\right)\wedge \vec{V}=\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle 0\\
\displaystyle 0\\
\displaystyle -a
\end{pmatrix}\wedge\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle a\left(x+y\right)\\
\displaystyle -ay\\
\displaystyle w_0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle -a^2 y\\
\displaystyle -a^2\left(x+y\right)\\
\displaystyle 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\wedge$ is the cross product.

I know that I should obtain
$$J.V=\vec{\text{rot}}\left(\vec{V}\right)\wedge \vec{V}+\vec{\text{grad}}\left(\frac{\vec{V}^2}{2}\right)$$
but here I obtain
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle a^2x\\
\displaystyle -a^2 x\\
\displaystyle 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

so where do i made a mistake please ?

Comment: There is a problem with $grad(V^2)$, the second element is not correct

Comment: Shouldnt it be the derivative of $a^2y^2$ ?

Comment: Just write what $V^2$ is and then take the gradient.